# record browse number of an article with laravel？

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.1, I am not familiar with the grammar，the question is: 
how to record the browse number of an article with laravel？I'd like to refer to an example.

Comment: you want to keep a count of how many times an article has been viewed ? what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to add a column in your articles table, let's call it "views".

Now in the controller that returns that view, you can just increment the column.

It should be something like this:

```
DB::table('articles')->where('id', 'some id')->increment('views');
```

Comment: could I ask another question? how to limit a count of publishing articles in fixed time，such as less than10 articles in one hour.